# Debugging with the Command Line

Tags: debugging, command-line, excel, vba

I'm writing a program with VBA, in order to manipulate Microsoft Project.

However, I am running into some trouble. I want to be able to do some debugging work. How can I open a command line in order to see what is going on with some printfs, which appear in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do your debuging with `MsgBox`? I think that will be way easier than getting VBA to spawn a command line. Actually I don't even get why you want to do that since there's a debugger included into VBA...

hth

K

Comment: I see your point... 
I have a debugger but I do a lot of processing in my code and the command line with prints will allow me to know what kind of information am I processing at the moment.

you understand?

Comment: I C, have you tried to output for debug information into a list box for example? should be piece of cake with vba.

Answer (score 1):

To open a command line from VBA you can use the Shell function (`shell("cmd.exe")`)

But for debugging VBA applications, the immediate window (alt+g) is a very, very nice feature.

Instead of doing printfs to a command line window you put some `debug.print` statements and watch them from the immediate window.  You can also pause execution and lookup/modify variables values in real-time.

Hope that helps